# How to make flex-wrap items wrap inline rather than as blocks?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, inline

When the title doesn't wrap (large screens), this behaves how I want: they take up minimal horizontal space while displaying as much of the url as possible (this is why I used flex).

When the title does wrap (smaller screens or realllly long title), the elements are no longer "inline" and there's a large block of unused whitespace after the title that could fit the url.

I've tried using an inline container but then either the title wraps in a weird way (have trouble reproducing) or the url doesn't truncate.

I'd prefer a CSS solution, but I'm not sure there is this goldilocks one. I've spent cumulatively a couple days trying to solve this, and have thus just given up.

You can view the problematic layout in context at https://stacker.news

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.url {
    font-size: 80%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    flex: 1 0 128px;
}

.inline-title {
  white-space: normal
}

.inline-url {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 128px;
  font-size: 80%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.inline-container {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span class="title">
    Some really long title that will wrap on small screens creating a block
  </span>
  <a class="url" href="#">
    www.example.com/a/long/link/that-should-truncate-when-there-is-not-space
  </a>
</div>

<div class="inline-container">
  <a class="inline-title">
    1Password Secrets Automation
  </a>
  <a class="inline-url" href="#">
    www.example.com/a/long/link/that-should-truncate-when-there-is-not-space
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's fair, but as stated I've tried other solutions. How do I achieve what I want without flexbox?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the way the box model works. There is no solution for it except to have all of the content be contiguous in a single wrapper and even then I don't think  it will do what you want.